# Should these two specific questions be tagged [feminism]?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, specific-tag, editing

[How can I use IPSkills on a conflict-avoidance strategy to memorably inform feminist group some arguments affect our community because misandristic?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/14092/how-to-politely-inform-a-group-of-feminists-some-of-their-arguments-are-misandri)

[How to politely encourage my girlfriend to support the value of men when with friends who make misandristic comments?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/14078/how-to-politely-encourage-my-girlfriend-to-support-the-value-of-men-when-with-fr)

Both of these questions specifically mention that the OP is asking about how to approach feminists. I figured that [feminism](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feminism) should apply and added it to both. The OP seems to disagree with the tagging and removed it.

Figured it would be better to ask here on meta than to edit against the OP's wishes again.

So does [feminism](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feminism) apply, and should it be reapplied?

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps we're misusing the tag entirely. Neither of the existing questions using it are *about* feminism, they're both about interacting with people who the question askers consider to be "feminists", either by the OP's definition or because the subject of the question has claimed to be a feminist. Regardless, that's really not the same thing. I'm not even sure questions about feminism would be on topic here.

As with the existing questions, the people involved in the questions are labeled (by the OP) as "feminists" but, by the same argument, I don't really think the question is *about* feminism and, so, tagging it [feminism](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feminism) seems wrong to me.

We do have tags for the type of relationship you have with a person, such as [friends](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/friends), or things that define the interaction somehow, such as [racial-issues](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/racial-issues).

I'd recommend that we use something like [gender-issues](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender-issues), which doesn't actually exist currently, but it would more broadly encapsulate these questions about gender discussions. This may even be better for use here than our current [gender](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender) tag.

That said, the questions are definitely *not* about humanism, so I've removed that tag from both and replaced it with tags I felt were more appropriate, though unrelated to the gender-specificity of the question.